# Reject sites with alexa rank smaller than x in input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

PHP - alexa.php

```
<?
$url = filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
web == (string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
echo $rank;
?>
```

Javascript - alexa.js

```
function alexa() {
 var $btn = $('#buttonreg');
 var $input = $('#domain');
 var url = $.trim($input.val());
 $.get('alexarank.php?url='+url, function(data){
  var alexa = parseInt(data);
  if ($.trim(data) == '' || alexa < 500000)
  {
   alert('We don't accept sites with alexa rank higher than 500.000.');
   $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
   else
    {
     $btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  }, 'text');
}
```

HTML - page.html

```
<input id="domain" class="txt" type="text" name="domain" size="25" value="" maxlength="255" onblur="alexa()"></input>
```

I need to echo the error alert('We don't accept sites with alexa rank higher than 500.000.'); when the user is adding his website on the registration form if his site alexa rank is smaller than 500.000. I have tested it and it doesn't work, it doesn't do anything.
Started testing it from php, the php works when i go in the browser http://www.testingsite.com?url=http://www.google.com it returns the right value so i am thinking that i have done something bad with the javascript or HTML.

Comment: alert('We don't accept sites with alexa rank higher than 500.000.');

That seems to have mismatching quotes.

Comment: You should try to put some debug lines in it first. Do a console log in the success function that outputs the data object, and after the $.get() add .done(), .fail() and .always() with similar log rules to see which get fired and what they receive. (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: @Stephan MullerDid not realized is Jquery, but still not loading after adding in the header loading of jquery-1.10.2.js or jquery-2.0.3.js. Don't know exactly how to debug i am a noob in this.

Comment: The $.get() function you had in there made me think it was jQuery, sorry if I was wrong. Anyway, debugging is simply going step by step through your code and checking if anything at all is happening, and if so if it's correct. Before the line `var alexa = parseInt(data);` add a line `console.log(data)` and check in your browser console (google that if necessary) if it outputs anything that looks like what your PHP is sending. If so, your AJAX works and you can start debugging the following rules. If not, it's the AJAX that's failing. Just try to determine where problems occur.

Comment: I just tried the link you posted below and it works for me! http://i.imgur.com/D2XEX64.png

Comment: @Stephan Muller It seams that it works for sites with no alexa rank.

Comment: Got the problem it was because i was using < 5000 instead of > 5000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make things clear what I mentioned in the comment.

```
alert('We don't accept sites with alexa rank higher than 500.000.');
```

should be replaced with

```
alert("We don't accept sites with alexa rank higher than 500.000.");
```

The first one (which you have in your code) has mismatching quotes, and obviously breaks the rest of the code. The single quote you used in " don't " is what broke everything.

EDIT:

Change your code to this and try. If still doesn't work, check js console.

```
function alexa() {
 var $btn = $('#buttonreg');
 var $input = $('#domain');
 var url = $.trim($input.val());
 $.get('alexarank.php?url='+url, function(data){
  if( typeof(data) == "undefined" ) return false;
  var alexa = parseInt(data);
  if ($.trim(data) == '' || alexa < 500000)
  {
   alert('We do not accept sites with alexa rank higher than 500.000.');
   $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
   else
    {
     $btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @Adrian did you check for any javascript error on the console? (eg: Firebug in Firefox)

Comment: @Adrian and which js file has what you said? I checked "common.js" no code seen.

Comment: 2 things, remove that 'text' which you have at the end of get() function. also do "console.log(data)" inside get(). and check the log. I cannot view your website because it forwards me after alerting "your country not supported"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38019/discussion-between-xfortyfourx-and-adrian)